# Monitor class events from userform

Tags: vba, excel, class, events, userform

I have a userform which assembles itself at runtime, by looking in a folder and extracting all the pictures from it into image-controls on my form. What makes the process a little more complex is that I'm also using the image-controls' events to run some code.

As a simplified example - I have a form which creates a picture at runtime, the picture has an on-click event to clear its contents. To do this I have a custom class to represent the image object

In a blank userform called "imgForm"

```
Dim oneImg As New clsImg 'our custom class

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set oneImg.myPic = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1") 'set some property of the class
oneImg.Init 'run some setup macro of the class
End Sub
```

In a class module called "clsImg"

```
Public WithEvents myPic As MSForms.Image

Public Sub Init() 'can't put in Class_Initialise as it is called before the set statement - so myPic is still empty at that point
myPic.Picture = LoadPicture(path/image)
End Sub

Public Sub myPic_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
onePic.Picture = Nothing
End Sub
```

**The problem is, this doesn't display the changes,** and I realised I needed a `imgForm.Repaint` in there somewhere - **the question is, where?**

### *Attempts*

First option is to put it in the `Init()` sub of `clsImg`. (ie. have a line `imgForm.Repaint` at the end of the click event) That works, but not ideal as the class can then only be used with the userform of the correct name.

---

A 2nd idea was to pass the userform as an argument to `Init()`

```
Public Sub Init(uf As UserForm) 'can't put in Class_Initialise as it is called before the set statement - so myPic is still empty at that point
myPic.Picture = LoadPicture(path/image)
uf.Repaint
End Sub
```

And called with

```
oneImg.Init Me
```

That works too, but would mean that wherever I require a repaint, I would have to pass the parameter which is also not ideal - the code is in reality a lot more complex than is shown here, so I don't want to have to add in this extra parameter unless necessary

---

The third option which I'm currently using is to pass the userform object to the class and save it there.

So with a `Public myForm As UserForm` at the top of my class module, I can pass the userform with the `Init(uf As UserForm)` and have a

```
Set myForm = uf 'Works with a private "myForm"/ class Property
```

Or I can set it directly from the userform code with a

```
Set clsImg.myForm = Me 'only if "myForm" is Public
```

But what does this do for memory - does saving the userform as a variable in my class take up a lot of memory? Bear in mind that in my real code I declare an array of `clsImg`s that can be of the order of >100 instances so I don't really want to be making copies of the UF in *each class* if that's what this method does. Also, it's ugly

## What I really want...

... is a way of *telling* the userform that it needs to repaint, rather than directly repainting from within the class. To me this says I need an event to occur in my class, which the userform *hears* with some custom event handler. Exactly how Worksheet_Change works, the sheet object raises a change event, the sheet class code handles it.

Is such a thing possible (I suppose I would have to declare `clsImg WithEvents` - can you do that for an array?), or is there a better alternative. I'm looking for a method which does not impede performance with a large number of classes declared, as well as one which is portable and easily readable. This is my first use of Classes so I may be missing something really obvious!

Comment: If you pass in the image as a control in your initialise, you can use the `.parent` property to get the form, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since good practice is that classes are self-contained (as you obviously know) the `clsImg` should indeed not have to be aware of the `UserForm` and thus shouldn't tell the UserForm to repaint.

What this calls for, is indeed that the clsImg raises an event that the UserForm hooks into, so it repaints based on that event, or, in your own words: "a way of telling the userform that it needs to repaint."

I replicated your Custom Class (`clsImg`) as follows (wanted to use a proper Setter / Getter, functionality doesn't really change)

`clsImg` Code:

```
Private WithEvents myPic As MSForms.Image 'Because we need the click event.
Public Event NeedToRepaint() 'Because we need to raise an event that the UserForm can hook into.
Public Property Let picture(value As MSForms.Image)
    Set myPic = value
End Property
Public Property Get picture() As MSForms.Image
    Set picture = myPic
End Property
Public Sub myPic_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    myPic.picture = Nothing
    RaiseEvent NeedToRepaint
End Sub
```

Next, in the UserForm we hook into this `NeedToRepaint` Event that's raised during the Event Handler of the `MouseDown` of the picture.

`UserForm1` Code:

```
Private WithEvents oneImg As clsImg 'Our custom class
Private Sub oneImg_NeedToRepaint() 'Handling the event of our custom class
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tmpCtrl As MSForms.Image
    Set oneImg = New clsImg
    Set tmpCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
    tmpCtrl.picture = LoadPicture("C:\Path\image.jpg")
    oneImg.picture = tmpCtrl
End Sub
```

The second part of your question is whether you can use this in an array.
The short answer is "no" - Each object would have to have it's own Event Handler. However, there are ways to work around this limitation by using a Collection or some similar approach. Still, this wrapper will have to be "UserForm aware" since that's where you'll be repainting. The approach would be something like in [this article](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/handle_multiple_userform_buttons_with_one_subroutine/)

**EDIT: A solution / workaround for not being able to use an Array:**

Since I really liked this question - Here's another approach.
We can apply somewhat of a PubSub pattern as follows:
I did a quick build for CommandButtons, but no reason that it can not be made for other classes of course.

`Publisher` class:

```
Public Event ButtonClicked(value As cButton)
Public Sub RegisterButtonClickEvent(value As cButton)
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(value)
End Sub
'Add any other events + RegisterSubs.
```

In a regular class, I setup a factory routine to keep this specific Publisher a singleton (as in: It will always be the very same in memory object that you're pointing at):

```
Private pub As Publisher
Public Function GetPublisher() As Publisher
    If pub Is Nothing Then
        Set pub = New Publisher
    End If
    Set GetPublisher = pub
End Function
```

Next, we have the UserForm (I just made one with 4 buttons) and the button class to utilize this Publisher. The Userform will just subscribe to the event it raises:
`Userform` code:

```
Private WithEvents pPub As Publisher 'Use the Publishers events.
Private button() As cButton 'Custom button array
Private Sub pPub_ButtonClicked(value As cButton) 'Hook into Published event.
    MsgBox value.button.Caption
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set pPub = GetPublisher 'Private publisher for getting it's event. Will be always the same object as long as you use "GetPublisher"

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton

    'Create an array of the buttons:
    i = -1
    For Each btn In Me.Controls
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve button(0 To i)
        Set button(i) = New cButton
            button(i).button = btn
    Next btn
End Sub
```

Last we have the `cButton` class, that centralizes the button events (through the array). Instead of handling each event individually, we just tell the publisher that an Event has been raised.:

```
Private WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton
Private pPub As Publisher
Public Event btnClicked()
Private Sub btn_Click()
    pPub.RegisterButtonClickEvent Me 'Pass the events to the publisher.
End Sub
Public Property Let button(value As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Set btn = value
End Property
Public Property Get button() As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set button = btn
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPub = GetPublisher
End Sub
```

With this approach we have one "Publisher" that can handle any event from specific classes that register the right event with it. You could also add image events, workbook events, etc.
The publisher itself raises the events we need based on what gets passed to it.
This way the UserForm can be agnostic of the button class and vice versa.
Based on what is supported in VBA, I'm quite confident this is the cleanest approach for your scenario. If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to see another answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. The main body of your answer is very clear and thanks for the tip on Letting/Getting. But as you highlight, this approach won't work for undefined array lengths as each one requires its own hard coded event handler - am I understanding you correctly? You allude to a workaround _using a Collection or some similar approach_ but the article you link just describes a method of assigning the controls to an array of classes. I've already got the exact same thing (albeit with runtime created controls not existing ones), but I don't see how that links in with any workaround?

Comment: I'm guessing what you mean is that I create another class which takes a WithEvents version of my first class, and that second class contains the repaint code. That way you assign the picture->firstclass and the firstclass->second class, each object handling the events of the one below it. Is that what you meant? Because what I really need is some way of collecting all the events from the first classes into a single event (like some OR statement with a paramArray input; I'm thinking aloud here) and then pass that collective event to my userform. Is anything like that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. Instead of Raising an Event you could call a regular module that has `UserForm1.Repaint` and just add an array of the custom class to the UserForm. The thing is, you can chain events just fine but somewhere you're going to need a specific handler for the object. The basic construction we're after is `Private WithEvents images() as clsImg` but that's not supported in VBA as far as I know. I'll see if I can find a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Greedo Please see my Edit. I think that this would be the cleanest approach as supported by VBA. Any other ideas --> I'd love to hear.

Comment: Glad the qu has sparked your interest. I was thinking of something along those lines; but the idea of a *factory routine* is genius and what I was lacking. I would suggest though that the event *does not* pass the button object. That's because (preference only) I think that only generic events should be handled by the userform/`Publisher` class (such as a `UF.Repaint` which has a *global* effect on all userform controls). Button-specific events should be handled in `cButton` meaning that the button object never actually has to be passed up the line. That might make the code more portable

Comment: Also, can the `GetPublisher()` code be coerced into the `Publisher` class or the UserForm code itself so you only need the 2 classes rather than 3? I'm just trying to work out whether this would be possible, but I guess a class can't initiate itself and I'm not sure if it could go in the userform as that would require the `cButton` class to have sight of the userform which is what we're trying to avoid. Perhaps you could place the Publisher code in the workbook class as that is already initiated and so you wouldn't need the Publisher factory class

Comment: `GetPublisher` can't be forced into the `Publisher` class - A class indeed can not instantiate itself. Of course you could do the initial instantiation in the Workbook, but whatever class wants to use it still need that factory routine. As to passing the button in the event - When raising any event it's up to you what you wish to pass as variables (if any) - Alter to suit your needs I'd say. The idea of having some Publisher is a design pattern that consists of having 3 classes in the first place. In VBA you don't really have the ability to do a fullblown `Subscribe()` unfortunately.

Comment: Still think it is the most suited design pattern for your situation though, given the limitations of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following,  If you pass the control as a control, you can use the parent.

In my form

```
Public c As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ctl As Control
Dim cls As clsCustomImage

    Set c = New Collection
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Image" Then
            Set cls = New clsCustomImage
            cls.init  ctl
            c.Add cls, CStr(c.Count)
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

and in my class, clsCustomImage

```
Private WithEvents i As MSForms.Image
Private frm As UserForm
public event evtRepaint
Public Sub init(c As control)
    Set frm = c.parent
    Set i = c
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set frm = Nothing
    Set i = Nothing
End Sub

'

Private Sub i_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    i.Picture = Nothing
    frm.Repaint
    raiseevent evtRepaint
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

To have a single handler, you'd need to look at something along these lines, in a class called say clsHoldAndHandle

```
Private c As Collection
Private f As UserForm
Private WithEvents cls As clsCustomImage

Public Sub AddControl(ctl As Control)
    Set cls = new clsCustomImage
    If f Is Nothing Then Set f = ctl.Parent
    cls.init ctl
    c.Add cls, CStr(c.Count)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set c = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub cls_evtRepaint()
    f.Repaint
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact you can still use a `MSForms.Image` not just a `control`. Then whenever I want to say `imgForm.Repaint` in my class, I can instead say `myPic.Parent.Repaint` - or indeed, as you have done, save `myPic.Parent` as a Userform object  in the `Init()` sub. But what about the bit you deleted, about declaring a public event? Might that be another way - if I have a collection/array of classes all raising the same Public event, and my userform contains the event handler for it? How would I write that in code?

Comment: With the event you still need the same code to call it, so you'd have raiseevent where repaint is, but you'd have to declare single instances of each image class.  Or have another class handling it, but again, will still need the `.parent`

Comment: So, as per my comment on [Rik Sportel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673568/6609896), is there no way to collect all the events together into a single event? Some kind of OR function on an undefined number of event inputs?

Comment: You could write your own collection class, and take one instance of the parent, so have a class with a collection and a userform, set the user form once, then call that way, but seems like you'd have a class for controlling your custom classes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this just listen for events from the last control added to the collection? I think there's some promise in [this approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44361), creating a function event handler that accepts arguments, but it looks pretty complicated!

Comment: Hi, yes, I put something along these lines.  I don't think there will be a solution that you desire.  Best just using the solution that works :(